# I'm trying to read a text file and find specific matches and print it , but my code does not working

Tags: java

I've put this to find string matches , just showing build successfully nothing else.I've put this to find string matches , just showing build successfully nothing else.I've put this to find string matches , just showing build successfully nothing else.

```
public class Lab1 {
    public static final String FileName = "E:\\test\\new.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FileName);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String r = null;
            r = br.readLine();

            String key = "int, float, if, else , double";
            String iden = "a, b, c, d, e , x , y , z";
            String mat = "int, float, if, else , double";
            String logi = "int, float, if, else , double";
            String oth = "int, float, if, else , double";


            if(r.contains(key)) {
                System.out.println(key.matches(r));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Could you add the content of your text file ?

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: ok... add an else block and print r, just for kicks.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what `r.contains(key)` mean? It wont return `true` for `"my float is super"` in `r`.

Comment: I tried to to check if the string r contains the value of string key , and I wanted to print the matches just then.

Comment: My input file looks like :

Comment: int a, b, c;
float d, e;
a = b = 5;
c = 6;
if ( a > b)
{
 c = a - b;
 e = d - 2.0;
}
else
{
 d = e + 6.0;
 b = a + c;
}

Comment: Do you need to match with all the 'key' words? If so you cannot use matches() here, matches() function will try to match with all the keys in the line. Because matches() function accepts regex as param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contains() doesn't work like that.

> Contains **returns true if and only if this string contains the
>   specified sequence of char values.**

What you could do is:

```
String key = "(int|float|if|else|double)"; // is a regex to check if one of the words exist
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(r);
while (matcher.find()) { // Checks if the matcher matches r.
  System.out.println(matcher.group()); // return all the words which matched
}
```

You don't have to use regex for this and simply do something like this:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("int", "float", "if", "else", "double");

Optional<String> possibleMatch = keys.stream()
    .filter(a::contains) // if a contains one of the keys return true
    .findFirst(); // find the first match 

if (possibleMatch.isPresent()) { // if a match is present
  System.out.println(possibleMatch.get()); // print the match
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro , I'll try it and let you know if this works for me

Comment: Aight nice. Could you mark your question as answered.

Comment: Identifiers?000

Comment: every character is showing , Eg: float has a , so this a also goes among identifiers

Comment: The variable r contains the String you want to test. If float is in the string you want to test, it will also show ofcourse.